# How to make a weapon with projectiles and weapon effects (fps) in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As for example in overwatch. in the frame on the right side of the screen you can see the weapon, the sight in the center of the screen. When shots are fired, you can see both a flying bullet and a tracer from it and a flash of a weapon, but at the same time the bullets fly to the center of the screen and not from the side and not obliquely, no matter how far or blickly you approach the target, if the bullet flies from the camera, how to do the same?
I tried to make a weapon that shoots from the barrel of a model, but you can't fool logic, well, respectively, if you release bullets from the camera, it doesn't look right.
(c# unity)

addition:
I did not express myself clearly, (I will use the example of overwatch) all the characters shooting projectiles shoot in a straight line and with a certain projectile speed, which adds mechanics (such as shooting ahead of time) while the weapon is visible on the screen and you can see how a bullet flies out of it. At the same time, the projectile flies in a straight line and into the "center of the screen"

and here is my code (which formally works, but does not fall into the center of the screen):

```
public class ProjectileGun : MonoBehaviour, Gun
{
    
    private float timerBetweenShoot;
    private int amoNow;
    private Camera fpsCam;


    public float timeBetweenShootSize;
    public int amo;
    public GameObject positionToSpawnBullet;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public Animator animator;
    public void altShoot()
    {
        //noHaveAltShoot
    }

    public void shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, positionToSpawnBullet.transform.position, positionToSpawnBullet.transform.rotation);
    }
    public void reload()
    {
        amoNow = amo;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        amoNow = amo;
        timerBetweenShoot = timeBetweenShootSize;
        fpsCam = Camera.current;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)){
            timerBetweenShoot = timerBetweenShoot - Time.deltaTime;
            if(timerBetweenShoot < 0){
                if( (amoNow > 0) ){
                    shoot();
                    animator.SetBool("Shoot", true);
                    animator.SetBool("Reload", false);
                    amoNow = amoNow - 1;
                }else{
                    animator.SetBool("Shoot", false);
                }
                timerBetweenShoot = timeBetweenShootSize;
            }
        }else{
            animator.SetBool("Shoot", false);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R)){
            if(amoNow < amo){
                reload();
                animator.SetBool("Reload", true);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your failed code would be helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Think about Soldier 76 on Overwatch. Gun animations and bullet launches work separately, and the actual bullets go out of the center. Think of it all as moving individually.
To sum up, it seems like a bullet is going out of the gun, but I actually think it looks like that because of animation and vfx, and the bullet only goes out in the center.

Comment: That's just the dilemma of what kind of "effects" show that a bullet flies from a weapon but actually flies from the center of the screen. However, the example with the soldier is a little incorrect, since that hitscan
and he does not have a flying bullet that we see, he just has a reycast from the camera and a flash effect on the barrel. But Mercy/She (without sight)/Genji/Hanzo/Phara
A couple of seconds and I will now insert an explanation into the question